# Difference between jmp and b?

Tags: assembly, lpc, nxp-microcontroller

What is the difference between `jmp` and `b` in assembly. I'm familiar with `jmp` which is an unconditional jump, but never seen `b` before.

Comment: Assembly is architecture-specific. Please tag your question with the relevant CPU architecture tag.

Comment: will do, thanks for the heads up!

Comment: lpc and nxp are not architectures they are part numbers and a chip company that uses a number of different architectures.   a full part number would be useful if you dont know the architecture.

Comment: there is one or a few that have both, but in general some use b and others jmp, understand this is just assembly, you read the documentation for the processor to see what each instruction does.

Comment: it is the LPC824. Can it be a cortex arm M0 architecture?

Answer (score 1):

`b` is ARM's equivalent for x86 / whatever `jmp`.  Unconditional branch.

On ARM, `bal` = Branch ALways.  (ARM's ability to predicate every instruction means that it has syntax to apply an "always" condition to every instruction in ARM mode.)

Other ISAs may use different mnemonics.

Comment: +1 To further clarify/add to this answer suggesting ARM's 'ability to predicate' and its clarification as to the ability to apply an "always" condition:
This conditional execution is based on the values of the Application Program Status Register (APSR) condition flags.

@Peter Cordes: Please feel to correct me if this sounds inaccurate.